# XDoclet-based Stateless Session Bean Compatibility Issue: ClassCastException in WebSphere 9.0.5

Tags: java, websphere, ejb, xdoclet

I have a legacy EJB application that was originally developed in Java 1.6 and deployed on WebSphere 8.5 more than a decade ago.
Recently, I upgraded the Java version to 1.8 and the WebSphere version to 9.0.5. The application works fine.

However, I'm encountering a peculiar issue related to a specific XDoclet-based stateless session bean. This bean is annotated with `@ejb.util generate = "physical".`

The issue occurs when the batch job starts first and creates the bean, and then the application attempts to use the bean. I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.omg.stub.javax.ejb._EJBHome_Stub incompatible with com.xxx.common.reference.interfaces.ReferenceDataBeanHome
```

If the application creates the bean first and then the batch job uses it, everything works as expected.

**XDoclet Generated Code:** 
The narrowing code is already generated by the XDoclet, we can't edit the code

```
 private static Object lookupHome(java.util.Hashtable environment, String jndiName, Class narrowTo) throws javax.naming.NamingException {
      // Obtain initial context
      javax.naming.InitialContext initialContext = new javax.naming.InitialContext(environment);
      try {
         Object objRef = initialContext.lookup(jndiName);
         // only narrow if necessary
         if (narrowTo.isInstance(java.rmi.Remote.class))
            return javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(objRef, narrowTo);
         else
            return objRef;
      } finally {
         initialContext.close();
      }
   }
```

**What I tried:**

I have changed the `@ejb.util generate = "logical".` based on the [IBM WebSphere suggestion](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/classcastexception-when-casting-remote-ejb-home-or-remote-interface-stub-instance) but the Batch job starts to fail if starts after the application creates the Bean

**Environment:**

- Java Version: 1.8
- WebSphere Version: 9.0.5

**Specifics:**

- The issue is tied to the usage of `@ejb.util generate = "physical"` with XDoclet.
- The exception occurs when the batch job initializes the bean before the application.

**Question:**

- What could be causing this ClassCastException when the batch job starts first?
- How can I ensure compatibility in both scenarios: when the application initializes the bean first and when the batch job does?
  Any insights, suggestions, or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that is failing with the ClassCastException is not calling `PortableRemoteObject.narrow()`.  Anytime a remote EJB is looked up in naming it should perform a `PortableRemoteObject.narrow`.

Often, code will work without the narrow because the ORB will attempt to narrow automatically, but this does not always work, depending on the classpath of the client at the time of the lookup. If the first lookup does not have the stub on the classpath, then you will get the EJBHome stub. Unfortuntely, this can then end up cached in Naming, which may effect other clients as well. Always performing the narrow avoids this issue.

Since the JNDI lookup is returning an `_EJBHome_Stub`, this means the JNDI name is for a remote home and that the thread context classloader does not have access to the target class, `ReferenceDataBeanHome`. Since the ORB is unable to load `_ReferenceDataBeanHome_Stub`, then it will return `_EJBHome_Stub` instead, which must be narrowed.

What is especially curious with this scenario is that the code does contain a call to narrow, but it is not being called, suggesting that `narrowTo.isInstance(java.rmi.Remote.class)` is returning `false`. Since the home being looked up is a remote home, the `narrowTo` class should implement `javax.ejb.EJBHome`, which extends `java.rmi.Remote` and therefore this method should return `true` and the narrow should be performed.

I recommend checking the following:

- check that the batch job code path is calling lookupHome with the proper remote JNDI name and proper remote home class. If the batch job code is passing the remote home JNDI name, but the local home interface class, then the narrow would always be skipped, but the application may work properly if the ORB has proactively narrowed due to an earlier lookup from another application.
- check that the `java.rmi.Remote` class is not packaged in the application or otherwise included on the application classpath. Basically, need to determine why the `narrowTo` parameter on `lookupHome` is failing the `isInstance` check. This could happen if `java.rmi.Remote` is loaded by two different classloaders.

Determining why `isInstance` is returning false is the best solution. Alternatively, you could make sure the `_ReferenceDataBeanHome_Stub` class is packaged with the batch application, and that may allow the ORB to proactively narrow; however this seems like a workaround.

Comment: Hi @Tracy thanks for the answer, I edited the question and added the XDoclet code
There is a narrowing code. it happens only if necessary
I am not sure how to alter the Xdoclet to make it not necessary

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @HariHaravelan I updated the answer based on the updated question. Since the generated code does contain the narrow, it seems the problem is that the narrow is being skipped. The way it is coded appears correct, as the narrow should always be called when looking up a remote home. Either the `narrowTo` class being passed is not remote, or there is something wrong with the classpath.  Hope the updated answer helps.